# How to extract a method from Django HTML?

Tags: django, methods, feature-extraction

My website (built with django) has pagination to not have to load too much content at once. The buttons to jump between the pages should always look the same. I found the following code on the internet which works great:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately I have to put this in each of my HTML files and have **duplicated code**. Is there a way to **extract** these few lines somewhere else and then only **link to them** in the respective HTML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write these in a specific file, for example `pagination.html`:

```
<!-- pagination.html -->
{% if is_paginated %}
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Then you can use the [**`{% include … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) to render this file in other templates:

```
<!-- some-other-template.html -->
<!-- ... -->
{% include 'path/to/pagination.html' %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Somehow didnt think of that.
I even used the {% extends ... %} somewhere else.
Just didnt came to my mind that something like {% include ... %} exist.